# How can I get this program to run in linear-time?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, runtime, computer-science

So I've been working on an assignment question for a few days now and I've been finding it exceedingly difficult to get this program to run in linear-time. I've made it work in O(n^2) but I want to get a perfect score.

Here is the question: 
      We're asked to change the duplicates of certain numbers into negatives ones and then send all the duplicates to the end of the array.

```
  For example, if the input array is [ 4 , 1 , 1 , 3 , 3 , 3 , 1 , 1 ], it
  reads [ 4 , 1 , 3 , 1 , -1 , -1 , -1 , -1 ] after squeeze() completes.
```

And here is my program:

```
int base = ints[ints.length -1];
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = ints.length - 1 ; i > 0 ; i--)
    {
        if (base == ints[i-1])
        {
            ints[i] = N_ONE;
            count++;
        } else {
            base = ints[i-1];
        }
    }
    int count2 = 0;
    for (int j = 0; (count) != count2 ; j++)
    {
        if (ints[j] == -1 && ints[j+1] != -1)
        {
            ints[j] = ints[j+1];
            ints[j+1] = N_ONE;
            count2 = 0;
            j = 0;
        } else if (ints[j] == -1 && ints[j+1] == -1){
            count2++;
        }
    }
}
```

My first loop works efficiently and it sets all the duplicates numbers as -1's, however not only is my second loop not in linear-runtime but I feel like it can be done in a simpler way. I've tried writing out the processes by hand but I still seem to only come up with methods that are O(n^2).

Does anyone of have suggestions or tips? Is there something really simple I am missing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do it in one pass, using an index for each of where you are reading and where you are writing. Only write once for reading a block of duplicates. When you run out of read elements, just fill the rest of the array with -1.

Comment: To find duplicates in _O(n)_ time, use a `HashSet<Integer>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept behind this solution is, as I suggested in a comment: Do it in one pass, using an index for each of where you are reading and where you are writing. Only write once for reading a block of duplicates. When you run out of read elements, just fill the rest of the array with -1.

Here is an implementation, in Java. As you can see I have not done much testing.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    testIt(new int[]{});
    testIt(new int[]{4, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 1});
    testIt(new int[]{1});
    testIt(new int[]{1,1});
    testIt(new int[]{1,2});
  }

  public static void testIt(int[] in) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in));
    squeeze(in);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(in));
    System.out.println();
  }

  public static void squeeze(int[] data) {
    int readIndex = 0;
    int writeIndex = 0;
    while(readIndex < data.length){
      if(readIndex == 0 || data[readIndex] != data[readIndex-1]){
        // Need to store this one
        data[writeIndex] = data[readIndex];
        writeIndex++;
      }
      readIndex++;
    }
    while(writeIndex < data.length){
      data[writeIndex] = -1;
      writeIndex++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You've done infinity times as much testing as the vast majority of people who post answers here.